# What happened to my Ubuntu system?

Tags: updates

I had my other computer set up to install updates automatically.
The Software updater downloaded and installed one and then immediately opened again and asked to download one for 139mb. Figuring it was safe, since it was in the Software Updater, I hit okay.

My screen froze, stayed at the Ubuntu 22.04 loading for so long I tried to get it started again by hitting reset.

Now that computer goes to the login prompt ... doesn't load the screen even when I enter my identity and password.

all it does is sit at the startup prompt *:/myname$:

I'm not only confused, I'm irritated. I've trusted Ubuntu since before 2012. This is the first experience where I am unable to sign on to my computer.
and don't ask for a screenshot of the mess, I don't have another computer to send the pictures with even if it could take one. Which it doesn't seem to be able to do.

Comment: Looks like your system is starting up in text mode, doesn't load the GUI. However, it's hard to figure out why from the very few information you gave.
Anyway, your system is probably working, only the graphical layer isn't. It should be fixable, but more details are definitely needed.

Comment: "*computer goes to the login prompt*" Which login prompt? The graphical login? Or text login?

Comment: The `$` indicates that your computer is at the bash prompt, likely as user `root` (Administrator in Linux). First step, type `dmesg | less` and hit `>` to place the text at the end. Wander backwards (cursor up) and look for "failed", "error", "warning", "missing", "not found" and such - tell what you find in your posting above; do EDIT and type away.

Comment: another problem from an update: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1481183/xf86enableio-failed-to-enable-i-o-ports-0000-03ff-operation-not-permitted   as it reaches a prompt it it probably the video card driver. It is the primairy ingredient of a desktop :)

Comment: For some reason my upgrade to 22.04.3 did the same thing.  It went blank and hung for hours.  Then it came back up to the text as well.  I had to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` on it to repair the installs, then rebooted and everything seemed fine after that.  I am not quite sure what is causing it, but it looks like one of the updates is killing the DM and then hanging.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue today on Ubuntu 22.04.3. Fixed it by:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

On my end, some of the drivers were also broken by the failed upgrade, so I fixed that issue with:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

Looks like the issue is caused by:
[Bug #2030262 System broken after upgrade](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/2030262)