# xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Operation not permitted)

Tags: updates, 22.04

After updated Ubuntu, I cant run desktop enviroment.
Here is Xorg file:

```
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   177.851] Current Operating System: Linux marcin-ubuntu 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64
[   177.851] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic root=UUID=33e39c1a-cfc2-4078-b447-06e28c80816c ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[   177.852] xorg-server 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   177.852] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
[   177.852]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   177.852] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   177.853] (==) Log file: "/home/marcin/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Aug  5 13:49:09 2023
[   178.067] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   178.216] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   178.216] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   178.216] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   178.216] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   178.236] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   178.236] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   178.236] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   178.236] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   178.236] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[   178.236] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   178.417] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   178.417]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   178.417] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   178.417]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   178.417] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   178.417]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   178.440] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   178.440]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   178.440] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   178.440]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   178.440] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[   178.440] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   178.440] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   178.440] (II) Loader magic: 0x55e2beb6a020
[   178.440] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   178.440]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   178.440]    X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
[   178.440]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
[   178.440]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   178.442] (++) using VT number 1

[   178.446] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[   178.449] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[   178.449] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card1
[   178.450] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card1 226:1 fd 13 paused 0
[   178.451] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   178.451] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0
[   178.452] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 14 paused 0
[   178.460] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:0166:144d:c0d1 rev 9, Mem @ 0xf7400000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   178.460] (--) PCI: (1@0:0:0) 10de:0fd1:144d:c0d1 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   178.522] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   178.598] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   179.740] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   179.740]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 1.0.0
[   179.740]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   179.804] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[   179.804] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[   179.804] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[   179.804] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   179.804] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   179.838] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   179.950] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   179.950]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 1.21.1
[   179.950]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   179.950]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   179.950] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   179.950] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   180.008] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   180.008]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.5.0
[   180.008]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   180.008]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   180.008] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   180.008] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   180.056] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   180.056]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 2.5.0
[   180.056]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   180.056]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   180.056] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   180.056] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   180.056] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   180.056] xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Operation not permitted)
[   180.057] (II) modeset(0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[   180.057] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   180.057] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   180.057] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   180.057] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   180.105] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   180.106]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 0.0.2
[   180.106]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   180.106] (II) modeset(G0): using drv /dev/dri/card1
[   180.106] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[   180.106] (II) modeset(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   180.107] (==) modeset(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[   180.107] (==) modeset(0): RGB weight 888
[   180.107] (==) modeset(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   180.107] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[   180.107] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[   180.107] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[   180.605] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   180.606]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 1.0.1
[   180.606]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   191.799] (II) modeset(0): glamor X acceleration enabled on Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)
[   191.799] (II) modeset(0): glamor initialized
[   191.800] (==) modeset(0): VariableRefresh: disabled
[   191.800] (==) modeset(0): AsyncFlipSecondaries: disabled
[   191.800] (II) modeset(0): Output LVDS-1 has no monitor section
[   191.801] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 has no monitor section
[   191.803] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 has no monitor section
[   191.803] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 has no monitor section
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output LVDS-1
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer: SEC  Model: 324a  Serial#: 0
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): Year: 2011  Week: 0
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): Digital Display Input
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 34  vert.: 19
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): Gamma: 2.20
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): No DPMS capabilities specified
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): redX: 0.570 redY: 0.340   greenX: 0.330 greenY: 0.560
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): blueX: 0.160 blueY: 0.135   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): Supported detailed timing:
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): clock: 70.7 MHz   Image Size:  344 x 194 mm
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): h_active: 1366  h_sync: 1414  h_sync_end 1446 h_blank_end 1486 h_border: 0
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): v_active: 768  v_sync: 770  v_sync_end 775 v_blanking: 792 v_border: 0
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): Unknown vendor-specific block f
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0):  SAMSUNG
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0):  LTN156AT190
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0): EDID (in hex):
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0):   00ffffffffffff004ca34a3200000000
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0):   00150103802213780a09259257548f29
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0):   22505400000001010101010101010101
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0):   0101010101019e1b5678500018303020
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0):   250058c2100000190000000f00000000
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0):   00000000002387026401000000fe0053
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0):   414d53554e470a2020202020000000fe
[   191.804] (II) modeset(0):   004c544e31353641543139300a2000b4
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Printing probed modes for output LVDS-1
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x60.1   70.70  1366 1414 1446 1486  768 770 775 792 -hsync -vsync (47.6 kHz eP)
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.1   64.10  1280 1328 1360 1440  720 723 728 741 +hsync -vsync (44.5 kHz d)
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.1   65.07  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz d)
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "960x720"x60.1  117.14  960 1024 1128 1300  720 720 722 750 doublescan -hsync +vsync (90.1 kHz d)
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "928x696"x60.1  109.19  928 976 1088 1264  696 696 698 719 doublescan -hsync +vsync (86.4 kHz d)
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "896x672"x60.1  102.50  896 960 1060 1224  672 672 674 697 doublescan -hsync +vsync (83.7 kHz d)
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x576"x60.1   42.18  1024 1072 1104 1184  576 579 584 593 +hsync -vsync (35.6 kHz d)
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "960x600"x60.1   77.09  960 984 1000 1040  600 601 604 617 doublescan +hsync -vsync (74.1 kHz d)
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "960x540"x60.1   37.41  960 1008 1040 1120  540 543 548 556 +hsync -vsync (33.4 kHz d)
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.1   38.45  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (37.5 kHz d)
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "840x525"x60.1   59.69  840 864 880 920  525 526 529 540 doublescan +hsync -vsync (64.9 kHz d)
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "864x486"x60.1   30.76  864 912 944 1024  486 489 494 500 +hsync -vsync (30.0 kHz d)
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "700x525"x60.1   61.10  700 744 820 940  525 526 532 541 doublescan +hsync +vsync (65.0 kHz d)
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x450"x60.1   48.95  800 824 840 880  450 451 454 463 doublescan +hsync -vsync (55.6 kHz d)
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x512"x60.1   54.05  640 664 720 844  512 512 514 533 doublescan +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz d)
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "700x450"x60.1   43.39  700 724 740 780  450 451 456 463 doublescan +hsync -vsync (55.6 kHz d)
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x60.1   25.23  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz d)
[   191.805] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x405"x60.1   22.15  720 768 800 880  405 408 413 419 +hsync -vsync (25.2 kHz d)
[   191.806] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "684x384"x60.1   36.26  684 708 724 764  384 385 390 395 doublescan +hsync -vsync (47.5 kHz d)
[   191.806] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x360"x60.1   17.97  640 688 720 800  360 363 368 374 +hsync -vsync (22.5 kHz d)
[   191.806] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "512x384"x60.1   32.54  512 524 592 672  384 385 388 403 doublescan -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz d)
[   191.806] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "512x288"x60.1   21.05  512 536 552 592  288 289 292 296 doublescan +hsync -vsync (35.6 kHz d)
[   191.806] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "480x270"x60.1   18.70  480 504 520 560  270 271 274 278 doublescan +hsync -vsync (33.4 kHz d)
[   191.806] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "400x300"x60.1   19.19  400 412 448 512  300 300 301 312 doublescan +hsync +vsync (37.5 kHz d)
[   191.806] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "432x243"x60.1   15.38  432 456 472 512  243 244 247 250 doublescan +hsync -vsync (30.0 kHz d)
[   191.806] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "320x240"x60.1   12.59  320 328 376 400  240 245 246 262 doublescan -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz d)
[   191.806] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "360x202"x60.1   11.05  360 384 400 440  202 204 206 209 doublescan +hsync -vsync (25.1 kHz d)
[   191.806] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "320x180"x60.1    8.99  320 344 360 400  180 181 184 187 doublescan +hsync -vsync (22.5 kHz d)
[   191.807] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output VGA-1
[   191.808] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output HDMI-1
[   191.808] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-1
[   191.808] (II) modeset(0): Output LVDS-1 connected
[   191.808] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 disconnected
[   191.808] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 disconnected
[   191.808] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 disconnected
[   191.808] (II) modeset(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[   191.808] (II) modeset(0): Output LVDS-1 using initial mode 1366x768 +0+0
[   191.808] (==) modeset(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   191.808] (==) modeset(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   191.808] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   191.808] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   191.808] (II) Module "fb" already built-in
[   192.139] (==) modeset(G0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[   192.139] (==) modeset(G0): RGB weight 888
[   192.139] (==) modeset(G0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   192.139] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[   192.139] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[   192.139] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[   192.139] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   192.139]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 1.0.1
[   192.139]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   194.127] (II) modeset(G0): glamor X acceleration enabled on NVE7
[   194.127] (II) modeset(G0): glamor initialized
[   194.139] (II) modeset(G0): Output VGA-1-2 has no monitor section
[   194.152] (II) modeset(G0): EDID for output VGA-1-2
[   194.152] (==) modeset(G0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   194.152] (==) modeset(G0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   194.152] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   194.152] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   194.152] (II) Module "fb" already built-in
[   194.152] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   194.152] (II) Unloading fbdev
[   194.152] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[   194.152] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[   194.152] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[   194.152] (II) Unloading vesa
[   194.706] (==) modeset(0): Backing store enabled
[   194.706] (==) modeset(0): Silken mouse enabled
[   194.758] (II) modeset(0): Initializing kms color map for depth 24, 8 bpc.
[   194.758] (==) modeset(0): DPMS enabled
[   194.759] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[   194.759] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: crocus
[   194.759] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[   195.039] (==) modeset(G0): Backing store enabled
[   195.039] (==) modeset(G0): Silken mouse enabled
[   195.040] (II) modeset(G0): Initializing kms color map for depth 24, 8 bpc.
[   195.040] (==) modeset(G0): DPMS enabled
[   195.040] (II) modeset(G0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[   195.040] (II) modeset(G0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: nouveau
[   195.040] (II) modeset(G0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nouveau
[  ...
[   195.088] (II) modeset(G0): Damage tracking initialized
[   195.088] (II) modeset(0): Damage tracking initialized
[   195.088] (II) modeset(0): Setting screen physical size to 361 x 203
[   195.677] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[   195.677] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   195.677] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[   195.678] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[   195.748] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   195.748]    compiled for 1.20.14, module version = 1.2.1
[   195.748]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   195.748]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[   195.748] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[   195.750] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event2 13:66 fd 32 paused 0
[   195.750] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   195.750] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[   195.819] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   195.819] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   195.820] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[   195.820] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[   195.820] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[   195.820] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   195.820] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "pl"
[   195.896] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   195.896] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   195.897] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event6)
[   195.897] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   195.897] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[   195.899] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event6 13:70 fd 35 paused 0
[   195.899] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[   195.899] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[   195.901] (II) event6  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   195.901] (II) event6  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[   195.901] (II) event6  - Video Bus: device removed
[   195.901] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input8/event6"
[   195.901] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[   195.901] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   195.901] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "pl"
[   195.903] (II) event6  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   195.903] (II) event6  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[   195.904] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event5)
[   195.904] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   195.904] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[   195.905] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event5 13:69 fd 36 paused 0
[   195.905] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[   195.905] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[   195.907] (II) event5  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   195.908] (II) event5  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[   195.908] (II) event5  - Video Bus: device removed
[   195.908] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:0d/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input7/event5"
[   195.908] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[   195.908] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   195.908] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "pl"
[   195.910] (II) event5  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   195.910] (II) event5  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[   195.911] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[   195.911] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   195.911] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[   195.912] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event1 13:65 fd 37 paused 0
[   195.912] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   195.912] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[   195.914] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   195.914] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   195.914] (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
[   195.914] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/event1"
[   195.914] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[   195.914] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   195.914] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "pl"
[   195.915] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   195.915] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   195.916] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
[   195.916] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   195.916] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   195.919] (II) config/udev: Adding input device WebCam SC-13HDL11939N: WebCam S (/dev/input/event7)
[   195.919] (**) WebCam SC-13HDL11939N: WebCam S: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   195.919] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'WebCam SC-13HDL11939N: WebCam S'
[   195.920] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event7 13:71 fd 38 paused 0
[   195.920] (**) WebCam SC-13HDL11939N: WebCam S: always reports core events
[   195.920] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[   195.922] (II) event7  - WebCam SC-13HDL11939N: WebCam S: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   195.922] (II) event7  - WebCam SC-13HDL11939N: WebCam S: device is a keyboard
[   195.922] (II) event7  - WebCam SC-13HDL11939N: WebCam S: device removed
[   195.922] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/input/input9/event7"
[   195.923] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "WebCam SC-13HDL11939N: WebCam S" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[   195.923] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   195.923] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "pl"
[   195.924] (II) event7  - WebCam SC-13HDL11939N: WebCam S: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   195.925] (II) event7  - WebCam SC-13HDL11939N: WebCam S: device is a keyboard
[   195.925] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event8)
[   195.925] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   195.925] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   195.926] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event9)
[   195.926] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   195.926] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   195.926] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event10)
[   195.926] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   195.926] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   195.927] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
[   195.927] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   195.927] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[   195.929] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 39 paused 0
[   195.929] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[   195.929] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[   195.930] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   195.930] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[   195.931] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[   195.931] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/event3"
[   195.931] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[   195.931] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   195.931] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "pl"
[   195.933] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   195.933] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[   195.935] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event4)
[   195.935] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[   195.935] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[   195.936] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event4 13:68 fd 40 paused 0
[   195.936] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[   195.936] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[   195.937] (II) event4  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[   195.939] (II) event4  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device is a touchpad
[   195.939] (II) event4  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device removed
[   195.940] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6/event4"
[   195.940] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 12)
[   195.941] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   195.941] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   195.941] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   195.941] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   195.942] (II) event4  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[   195.944] (II) event4  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device is a touchpad
[   195.945] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[   195.945] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   195.945] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   289.617] (**) Option "fd" "32"
[   289.617] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[   289.617] (**) Option "fd" "35"
[   289.617] (II) event6  - Video Bus: device removed
[   289.617] (**) Option "fd" "36"
[   289.617] (II) event5  - Video Bus: device removed
[   289.617] (**) Option "fd" "37"
[   289.617] (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
[   289.617] (**) Option "fd" "38"
[   289.617] (II) event7  - WebCam SC-13HDL11939N: WebCam S: device removed
[   289.618] (**) Option "fd" "39"
[   289.618] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[   289.618] (**) Option "fd" "40"
[   289.618] (II) event4  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device removed
[   289.631] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   289.631] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:68
[   289.675] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   289.675] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:67
[   289.715] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   289.715] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:71
[   289.775] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   289.775] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:65
[   289.791] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   289.791] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:69
[   289.807] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   289.807] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:70
[   289.831] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   289.831] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:66
[   290.233] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

When Ubuntu starts it takes me to command line login.
I dont know what I should do more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a lot of people are having similar issues today.
In my case, on Ubuntu 22.04.3 I fixed the issue by installing ubuntu-desktop:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

I also had issues with some of the drivers, so I reinstalled them with:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

Looks like the issue is caused by:
[Bug #2030262 System broken after upgrade](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/2030262)

Comment: Your advise works I did sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop and it works now. Thanks a lot.